# Strange behavior of UIScrollView with Constraints and RTL

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, right-to-left, nslayoutconstraint

I have an horizontal scroll view on which i add views dynamically.
On LTR languages everything work fine, i add views one after the other from left to right.
On RTL the problem is that the views always added to the left of the scroll instead of to the right like in every other controller, the **really** strange staff that the order of the views is added correctly, to the left of the first view so they are ordered from right to left but outside of the scroll view on -x.

Here is my code when i add a new View:

```
Tag* tag = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tag" ];
[_scroller addSubview:tag.view];
[tags addObject:tag];
Tag* prev = nil
for (Tag* tag in tags)
{
    if (prev == nil)
    {
        [_scroller addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tag.view 
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading                                                                                          
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                     toItem:_scroller
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                 multiplier:1.0f
                                                                   constant:0]];
    }
    else
    {
        [_scroller addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[prev]-10-[tag]"
                                                                          options:0
                                                                          metrics:nil
                                                                            views:@{@"tag" : tag.view, @"prev" : prev.view}]];
    }

    [_scroller addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tag.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:_scroller
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                             multiplier:1.0f
                                                               constant:0]];
    prev = tag;

}
```

Here is an image of how it suppose to work on LTR and RTL and how it actually works
[image]

Comment: you issue is for LTR views should be LTR and for RTL views should be RTL... but for RTL you are getting LTR view is this the issue?

Comment: No, its mixed, when i'm on RTL, the added views (Tag) are mirrored and they are RTL. The order of the view are RTL also, the second is left to the first and so on. But The contentView is LTR it start from the left edge of the scroll view and further away.
[[tag3][tag2][tag1](left edge of scrollview)--------(right edge of scrollview)]

Comment: have you tried reversing the array in this scenario (suppose original is 1 2 3 making it to show like 3 2 1 )

Comment: Yes i did, it didnt get the result i wanted. it started from the left edge of the scroll view to the right and the view that supposed to be the first was in the middle of the scrollview, it should be on the right and start from there to the left.

Comment: can you show a rough screen how you want it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a better approach might be to use a `UICollectionView`. Then if you want to start it from the right side you could possibly do something like this:

```
NSIndexPath *lastIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:data.count - 1 
                                             inSection:0];
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:lastIndex 
                            atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionRight 
                                    animated:NO];
```

This way the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` can handle the placement for you.

Comment: This is not necessary, see the actual issue in my post below.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this behavior of `UIScrollView` is that you forgot to attach the `trailingAnchor` of the last element (#4) to the scroll view's `trailingAnchor`.

The `leadingAnchor` of both the scroll view and element #1 are attached to each other (see below in green). The scroll view's content rect however naturally spans into the positive coordinate directions, from origin `(0,0)` to right, down `(+x, +y)`. In your case the scroll view's content size is of width `0` because nothing is between scroll view's `leadingAnchor` and `trailingAnchor`.

[image]

So below your `[_scroller addConstraints:_constraint];` add something like (pseudo code):

```
if tag == lastTag {
  NSLAyoutconstraints.activate([
    tag.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor)
  ])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
UIView *baseView;
UILabel *titleLabel;
NSMutableArray *infoArray ;
UIScrollView *mainscrollview;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

infoArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
   NSLog(@"%@",infoArray);
mainscrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 380)];
mainscrollview.delegate=self;
mainscrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320*infoArray.count, 0);
[self.view addSubview:mainscrollview];
[self sscrollcontent:@"LTR"];//LTR for Lefttoright other than LTR it will show RTL
}
-(void)sscrollcontent:(NSString *)flowtype
{
int xaxis=0;
for (int i=0; i<infoArray.count; i++) {
    baseView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xaxis, 0, 320, 380)];
    [mainscrollview addSubview:baseView];
    titleLabel =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];
    titleLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    if ([flowtype isEqualToString:@"LTR"]) {
        titleLabel.text=infoArray[i];

    }
    else
    {
        titleLabel.text=infoArray[infoArray.count-i-1];

    }
    [baseView addSubview:titleLabel];
    xaxis=xaxis+320;
}
}

@end
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: This method will not work for me, as i need to work with constraints and have multiple views on the same time on the screen, not paging.

Answer (score 1):

This is my sample code.

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  testConstraint
//
//  Created by stevenj on 2014. 3. 24..
//  Copyright (c) 2014년 Steven Jiang. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"


@interface TagView : UILabel
- (void)setNumber:(NSInteger)num;
@end

@implementation TagView

- (void)setNumber:(NSInteger)num
{
    [self setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",num]];
}

@end

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *scroller;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tags;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *constraint;

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize scroller = _scroller;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _tags = [NSMutableArray new];
    _constraint = [NSMutableArray new];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //step.1 create scroll view
    _scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 60)];
    [_scroller setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [_scroller removeConstraints:[_scroller constraints]];
    [_scroller setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];

    [self.view addSubview:_scroller];


    //step.2 add tag view
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        TagView *tag = [[TagView alloc] init];

        [tag setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 30, 50, 30)];
        [tag setNumber:i];

        [tag.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [tag setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

        [_scroller addSubview:tag];
        [_tags addObject:tag];
    }

    //step.3 update contraints
    [self myUpdateConstraints];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)myUpdateConstraints
{
    [_constraint removeAllObjects];

    TagView* prev = nil;
    for (TagView* tag in _tags)
    {
        [tag setNumber:[_tags indexOfObject:tag]];

        if (prev == nil)
        {

            [_constraint addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(<=300)-[tag]-20-|"
                                                                                     options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                                       views:@{@"tag" : tag}]];
        }
        else
        {
            [_constraint addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[tag]-10-[prev]"
                                                                              options:0
                                                                              metrics:nil
                                                                                views:@{@"tag" : tag, @"prev" : prev}]];

        }

        [_scroller addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tag
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:_scroller
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                             multiplier:1.0f
                                                               constant:0]];

        prev = tag;

    }
    [_scroller addConstraints:_constraint];
}
@end
```

Hopes it could help you.